# Difference of two-dimension PHP arrays on given keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.  One comes from a database, and I can order how ever I want.
The second comes from a 3rd party api, and I have no control over the order. I am trying to determine the difference based on three keys (`pk1`, `pk2`, `pk3`) such as shown under `$desired`.

```
$array1=[
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>1,"attr2"=>3],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>2,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>3,"attr2"=>1],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>2,"attr1"=>2,"attr2"=>3],
];

$array2=[
    ["pk1"=>2,"pk2"=>2,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>3,"attr2"=>1],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk3"=>2,"pk2"=>1,"attr1"=>4,"attr2"=>3],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>1,"attr2"=>3],
];

$desired=[
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>1,"array1"=>["attr1"=>1,"attr2"=>3],"array2"=>["attr1"=>1,"attr2"=>3]],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>2,"pk3"=>1,"array1"=>["attr1"=>3,"attr2"=>1],"array2"=>null],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>2,"array1"=>["attr1"=>2,"attr2"=>3],"array2"=>["attr1"=>4,"attr2"=>3]],
    ["pk1"=>2,"pk2"=>2,"pk3"=>1,"array1"=>null,"array2"=>["attr1"=>3,"attr2"=>1]]
];
```

Comment: You are going to have to explain your problem in detail, its not at all obvious from the code

Comment: Create unique keys from `pk`s and compare them.

Comment: @u_mulder  I am currently starting to do so using `$array["$arr[pk1]~$arr[pk2]~$arr[pk3]"]`  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Steve  I have two sets of data.  I wish to display both sets based on a 3-key composite key so if different the user can select which one they wish to use.  The three key part is what makes it difficult under php.  SQL would be easy, but the second array is not in a database which I control.

Answer (score 1):

u_mulder, you beat me to it!  I am up with the following, however, assuming your solution works, like yours more.

```
<?php

$array1=[
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>1,"attr2"=>3],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>2,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>3,"attr2"=>1],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>2,"attr1"=>2,"attr2"=>3],
];

$array2=[
    ["pk1"=>2,"pk2"=>2,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>3,"attr2"=>1],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk3"=>2,"pk2"=>1,"attr1"=>4,"attr2"=>3],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>1,"attr2"=>3],
];

$desired=[
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>1,"array1"=>["attr1"=>1,"attr2"=>3],"array2"=>["attr1"=>1,"attr2"=>3]],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>2,"pk3"=>1,"array1"=>["attr1"=>3,"attr2"=>1],"array2"=>null],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>2,"array1"=>["attr1"=>2,"attr2"=>3],"array2"=>["attr1"=>4,"attr2"=>3]],
    ["pk1"=>2,"pk2"=>2,"pk3"=>1,"array1"=>null,"array2"=>["attr1"=>3,"attr2"=>1]]
];
echo('$array1');print_r($array1);
echo('$array2');print_r($array2);
echo('$desired');print_r($desired);

$array=[];
foreach($array1 as $arr) {
    $array["$arr[pk1]~$arr[pk2]~$arr[pk3]"]=["pk1"=>$arr['pk1'],"pk2"=>$arr['pk2'],"pk3"=>$arr['pk3'],"array1"=>["attr1"=>$arr['attr1'],"attr2"=>$arr['attr2']],"array2"=>null];
}
foreach($array2 as $arr) {
    if(isset($array["$arr[pk1]~$arr[pk2]~$arr[pk3]"])) {
        $array["$arr[pk1]~$arr[pk2]~$arr[pk3]"]['array2']=["attr1"=>$arr['attr1'],"attr2"=>$arr['attr2']];
    }
    else {
        $array[]=["pk1"=>$arr['pk1'],"pk2"=>$arr['pk2'],"pk3"=>$arr['pk3'],"array1"=>null, "array2"=>["attr1"=>$arr['attr1'],"attr2"=>$arr['attr2']]];
    }
}
$array=array_values($array);
echo('$array');print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Full solution using unique keys, created from `pk`-keys:

```
// delimiter for creating unique keys
const DELIMITER = '~';

// source arrays
$array1=[
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>1,"attr2"=>3],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>2,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>3,"attr2"=>1],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>2,"attr1"=>2,"attr2"=>3],
];

$array2=[
    ["pk1"=>2,"pk2"=>2,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>3,"attr2"=>1],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk3"=>2,"pk2"=>1,"attr1"=>4,"attr2"=>3],
    ["pk1"=>1,"pk2"=>1,"pk3"=>1,"attr1"=>1,"attr2"=>3],
];

// function to create new arrays with unique keys from source arrays
function doSmth($arr) 
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        // new key is created via concatenating pk-keys
        $result[$item["pk1"] . DELIMITER . $item["pk2"] . DELIMITER . $item["pk3"]] = [
            "attr1"=>$item["attr1"],
            "attr2"=>$item["attr2"],
        ];
    }

    return $result;
}

// creating new arrays
$narr1 = doSmth($array1);
$narr2 = doSmth($array2);

// target array
$desired = [];
foreach ($narr1 as $k => $v) {
    // restore pk-keys from $k
    $parts = explode(DELIMITER, $k);
    $desired[] = [
        'pk1' => $parts[0],
        'pk2' => $parts[1],
        'pk3' => $parts[2],
        'array1' => $v,
        // if same key exists in `$narr2` - use it
        'array2' => isset($narr2[$k])? $narr2[$k] : null
    ];
    if (isset($narr2[$k])) {
        // unset value from `$narr2`
        unset($narr2[$k]);
    }
}

// if something left in `$narr2` - add it to target array
foreach ($narr2 as $k => $v) {
    $parts = explode(DELIMITER, $k);
    $desired[] = [
        'pk1' => $parts[0],
        'pk2' => $parts[1],
        'pk3' => $parts[2],
        'array1' => null,
        'array2' => $v,
    ];
}

echo'<pre>',print_r($desired),'</pre>';
```